# Django rest framework saving thumbnail image

Tags: python, django, rest, python-imaging-library, django-rest-framework

I've recently started developing with django + python and everything was going very smooth until I got stuck into a problem that probably is very simple but I can not solve with my inexperience with the framework/language.

I'm receiving an JSON object through an HTTP Request which contains some data and 2 pictures. Prior to those 2 pictures I wanted to save a thumbnail from one of them but I don't see to get that task done. I can save all the data easily including the 2 images. But I can not see to find a way to generate a way an have that in the DB also, as well the folder structure that I want.

My folders should look like:

```
pictures
   user
      originals
      processed
      thumbnails
   otherUser
       originals
       processed
       thumbnails
```

My goal is: Receive 2 pictures, create a thumbnail from one of them and them save all 3 pictures in 3 separate folders and the path to the Database.

Here's how my model code looks like.

```
class SomeData(models.Model):
    owner = models.ForeignKey('auth.User', related_name='canopeo_data')
    adjustments = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    latitude = GeopositionField()
    longitude = GeopositionField()
    notes = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
    original_image = models.ImageField(upload_to=original_image, max_length=255, blank=True)
    processed_image = models.ImageField(null=False, upload_to=processed_image, max_length=255)
    thumbnail_image = models.ImageField(null=False, upload_to=thumbnail_image, max_length=255)
    date_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('date_time',)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(SomeData, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

def original_image(self, filename):
    url = "pictures/%s/originals/%s" % (self.owner.username, filename)
    return url


def processed_image(self, filename):
    url = "pictures/%s/processed/%s" % (self.owner.username, filename)
    return url


def thumbnail_image(self, filename):
    url = "pictures/%s/thumbnail/%s" % (self.owner.username, filename)
    return url
```

Serializer code...

```
class SomeDataSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
#url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='data', format='html')
owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')
thumbnail_image = serializers.Field(source='original_image')

class Meta:
    model = SomeData
    fields = ('url', 'adjustments', 'latitude', 'longitude', 'notes', 'original_image', 'processed_image',)
```

View code...

```
class SomeDataViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
queryset = SomeData.objects.all()
serializer_class = SomeDataSerializer
permission_classes = (permissions.IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly,)

def pre_save(self, obj):
    obj.owner = self.request.user
```

I've tried many things such as easy_thumbnails, sorl_thumbnail, and some pre made methods on how to do it.. but I can't see to find a solution specific for what I've been wanting.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you have mistake in definition of the `SomeDataSerializer`. In model `SomeData` field original_image defined as `ImageField`, but in serialiser it's just `Field`, not [ImageField](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields#imagefield). You should use correct field type:

```
class SomeDataSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    #url = serializers.HyperlinkedRelatedField(view_name='data', format='html')
    owner = serializers.Field(source='owner.username')
    thumbnail_image = serializers.ImageField(source='original_image')
    ...
```

Comment: Thank You!! I put my save thumbnail method back and modified the seralizer field. Not the thumbnail is saving properly!!